Springboot java unit tests failing after upgrade from 3.1.8 to 3.4.0
Have upgraded springboot from 3.1.8 to 3.4.0
Some of the tests are failing with error - "Unable to load region from any of the providers in the chain".
application.yml
cloud:
  aws:
    region:
      static: ap-southeast-2

Tests fail with below error:
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.SecretsManagerClient]: Factory method 'secretsManagerClient' threw exception with message: Unable to load region from any of the providers in the chain software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain@788ac757: [software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.SystemSettingsRegionProvider@3a0b36d7: Unable to load region from system settings. Region must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_REGION) or  system property (aws.region)., software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.AwsProfileRegionProvider@3a5df765: No region provided in profile: default, software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.InstanceProfileRegionProvider@1aa5c2f2: Unable to contact EC2 metadata service.]
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.lambda$instantiate$0(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:199)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiateWithFactoryMethod(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:88)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:168)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load region from any of the providers in the chain software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain@788ac757: [software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.SystemSettingsRegionProvider@3a0b36d7: Unable to load region from system settings. Region must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_REGION) or  system property (aws.region)., software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.AwsProfileRegionProvider@3a5df765: No region provided in profile: default, software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.InstanceProfileRegionProvider@1aa5c2f2: Unable to contact EC2 metadata service.]
    at app//software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:111)
    at app//software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.AwsRegionProviderChain.getRegion(AwsRegionProviderChain.java:70)
    at app//io.awspring.cloud.autoconfigure.core.AwsClientBuilderConfigurer.resolveRegion(AwsClientBuilderConfigurer.java:95)
    at app//io.awspring.cloud.autoconfigure.core.AwsClientBuilderConfigurer.resolveRegion(AwsClientBuilderConfigurer.java:82)
    at app//io.awspring.cloud.autoconfigure.core.AwsClientBuilderConfigurer.configure(AwsClientBuilderConfigurer.java:63)
    at app//io.awspring.cloud.autoconfigure.config.secretsmanager.SecretsManagerAutoConfiguration.secretsManagerClient(SecretsManagerAutoConfiguration.java:54)
    at java.base@17.0.12/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.lambda$instantiate$0(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
    ... 49 more

Can someone please help how to fix this?

What is the failure?

Tests are failing with "Unable to load region from any of the providers in the chain". I don't know why I am getting a region error with the new springboot version.
